# WPF: How to change properties of a datagrid column when mouse is over the header of the column?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have a datagrid in my software. This one shows rows of results. 
We use XAML styles to format it with style and data triggers for special behavior.

My goal: When I go over the column header, I want that the header cell and all the cells of the column get a border on the right (or same background color is ok).

How can I get this result?

For the moment, with the following style, I get the mouse over working on the header:

```
<Style x:Key="DataGridColumnHeaderGroups" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource SourceSansPro-Bold}" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="35" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource White}" />
    <Setter Property="SeparatorBrush" Value="{StaticResource Gray}" />
    <Setter Property="SeparatorVisibility" Value="Visible" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                <Grid x:Name="topGrid">
                    <themes:DataGridHeaderBorder Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                                 BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                                 BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                                 IsClickable="{TemplateBinding CanUserSort}"
                                                 IsHovered="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}"
                                                 IsPressed="{TemplateBinding IsPressed}"
                                                 Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                                 SeparatorBrush="{TemplateBinding SeparatorBrush}"
                                                 SeparatorVisibility="{TemplateBinding SeparatorVisibility}"
                                                 SortDirection="{TemplateBinding SortDirection}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="0"
                                              HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                              VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                              SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                            <Path x:Name="SortArrow"
                                  Grid.Column="1"
                                  Width="8"
                                  Height="6"
                                  Margin="2,0,5,0"
                                  HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                  VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                  Data="M0,0 L1,0 0.5,1 z"
                                  Fill="Black"
                                  Opacity="0.5"
                                  RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.4"
                                  Stretch="Fill"
                                  Visibility="Collapsed" />
                        </Grid>
                    </themes:DataGridHeaderBorder>
                    <Thumb x:Name="PART_LeftHeaderGripper"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                           Style="{StaticResource ColumnHeaderGripperStyle}" />
                    <Thumb x:Name="PART_RightHeaderGripper"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                           Style="{StaticResource ColumnHeaderGripperStyle}" />
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="SortDirection" Value="Ascending">
                        <Setter TargetName="SortArrow" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                        <Setter TargetName="SortArrow" Property="RenderTransform">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <RotateTransform Angle="180" />
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="SortDirection" Value="Descending">
                        <Setter TargetName="SortArrow" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="GreenYellow" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I have also the following style for the cells, but they are acting on rows and not column as I would like to have:

```
 <Style x:Key="DataGridCellGroups" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="35" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top" />
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="7" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0 0 3 0" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                        SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                    <ContentPresenter Margin="5,8,10,8"
                                      VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                      SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Grid Selected Row}" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource Gray Darker}" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

How can I set the background of the column, with styles, when `IsMousover = true` in the header?

**EDIT:** we have the following constraints: Work with style, propagate mouseover background to all column cells when the mouse overs the header of the column.

Answer (score 0):

How about handling `AutoGeneratingColumn`?

```
    private void DataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
    {
        var header = new DataGridColumnHeader() { Content = e.PropertyName }; ;
        e.Column.Header = header;
        header.MouseEnter += Header_MouseEnter;
        header.MouseLeave += Header_MouseLeave;

    }

    private void Header_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        ((DataGridColumnHeader)sender).Column.CellStyle = null;
    }

    private void Header_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        ((DataGridColumnHeader)sender).Column.CellStyle = TryFindResource("cellStyle") as Style;
    }
```

and Xaml:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell" x:Key="cellStyle">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightBlue"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<DataGrid DataContext="{Binding}" ItemsSource="{Binding Models}" AutoGeneratingColumn="DataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn" />
```

Comment: HI, We have different styles on different column AND work with styles as we have many such Grids. We envisaged a Custom control, but it is over-killed for us. So we try to work with Styles. Additionally, your solution to handle the event in the header is ok, but we got it already and it does not propagate a background/border to all the cells of the column

Comment: hi, how do set the itemssource of the datagrid?